# Term for repeating a part of what the interlocutor has just said so that they clarify it

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

When the interlocutor says a word or something that you do not understand or that needs more clarification, so you repeat that part expecting them to explain further, is there a term in grammar or an expression that refers to this in English?

e.g. Harry Potter:

> A: It's Alistair Moody, the aurour!
>   B: Aurour?!

e.g. Game of Thrones:

> Daenerys Targaryan: Where's Daario Naharis? Where is Grey-worm?
>    Ser Selmy: They are gambling, your grace.
>   Daenerys Targaryan: Gambling?!

Comment: Ehm,. "echoing"? I'm not sure there's a specific  word for doing that with the purpose of having it clarified.

Comment: *"Gambling?!", **queried** Daenerys*.

Comment: A hypernym is _echo question_. But these can also have different forms: 'I put it in the chifforobe.' ... 'You put it _**where**_?

Comment: I'd probably use something along the lines of "restate".

Answer (score -1):

"repeating it back to them" or "repeating it for clarification" seem like reasonable expressions that many English speakers would understand.

You could also use the words "questioning" or "questioned".

"Gambling?!" questioned Daenerys.

-or-

"Aurour?!" said Harry, questioning.

Comment: Use citations in answers, if you please.

Comment: What citations do you propose? I'm referencing the original poster. The example sentences I presented were constructed by me.

Answer (score -1):

When you are "repeating something in order to emphasize it or make it very clear to people," you are *[reiterating](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/reiterate)* what they said.

Comment: That is completely accurate. It is also completely irrelevant.